# Input matching with file not working properly - Java

Tags: java, file-io

** This method actually returns true when correct. The issue now has to do with LoginModule (A JAAS feature).

In my Java method below, I read lines from a file, "file.txt". While reading I output each line(This works fine), and then I check each line to match a string "creds" which is made up of a username password combination. I have tried to test with "creds", exact strings, and as you can see below using three different types of matching methods. None work and the return boolean "result" is always false. Has anyone encountered a similar problem before or would be able to help me?

```
        // Now perform validation. For login can either read from a file or a 
        // database. You can also incorporate secure password  handling here. 
        System.out.println("Checking username and password: " + username +"/" + password);

        String creds = username + ',' + password;
        boolean result = false;
        try {

              File file = new File("file.txt");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String line;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if(line == creds || line.equals(creds) || line.contains(creds)){
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                br.close();
                fr.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return result; // successful login.


    }
```

The file the method reads looks like this:

```
alicebob,thisissecure
tracyadam,mypass1
```

Comment: can you post the contents of the input file?

Comment: `line == creds` will only work if the two object references are the same. To test equality of two strings, you need to use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` (which you have).

Comment: I just tested it out, it works for me. Are you sure that your creds match the line exactly? I see that you print username/password, but are using username,password in the cred variable. Which are you using in the file?

Comment: @DustinF The print you are talking about is simply just a string I print out. The print that i was reffering to that works is System.out.println(line); I do this so that I know the file is being read line by line, and as I said this works fine

Comment: check for extra space in file as well as in `username` and `password` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was improper configuration of LoginModule. I had a floating boolean that I need to declare True upon the matching method. Since this was false, my login failed overtime. Goes to show, know your environment and proper class configuration.

Heres the Java LoginModule I'm referring to:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html